# Callback function not working with css library

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this simple part of code where callback function is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".target:nth-child(3)").addClass("animated shake",function(){
      $("body").addClass("animated hinge")
    });
  });
```

first function works just fine ( elements are shaking) but nothing happens after that.

I'm also using this css library:
https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css

Comment: According to [the documentation, `.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) doesn't accept a callback function as a second argument. (It does optionally accept one as its only argument, but not for the purpose you are trying to use it for.)

Comment: Only the jQueryUI version of the `addClass()` function only accepts a callback parameter - not the plain jQuery version: http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a callback function in this case as the Jquery AddClass is **not a asnychronous method** i.e. the next statement will be executed only once addClass is executed.

**This should simply work in your case:**

```
$(".target:nth-child(3)").addClass("animated shake");
  $("body").addClass("animated hinge")
```

Comment: So if the first CSS class has some associated (non-JS) animation, will the second one be added before or after that animation completes?

Comment: Implicitly, it doesn't know about non-js animations. **You'll have to handle that thing yourself using setTimeout function.**

Comment: @DJYadav thanks for your answer. I've just tested your solution and it looks like both functions are executed simultaneously, not one after another ( which is what I'm aiming to achieve)

Comment: @Pawel - It would help if you edited your question to more clearly explain that adding the first class causes CSS-based animation and that you want to wait for that to complete before adding the other class. (If indeed that is what you are trying to do.)

Comment: @Pawel Yeah cool. BTW, They seem to be executed simultaneously, but they are executed one after another only in the real scenario. The function serves the purpose of just adding the class so that is just ultra fast to execute. The time is taken by animation only which is not a part of js in this case.**I would like to suggest you to read more about synchronous and asynchronous functions in depth.**

Comment: @nnnnnn  You're right that's exactly what I wanted to achieve, and yeah I should've explain it more clearly, sorry about that.      so the only solution to that is to add setTimeout function? ( as DJ Yadav mentioned above)

Comment: @DJYadav So the only solution to that is to add setTimeout function? ( as You mentioned above)

Comment: For this kind of thing, yes the only possibility is setTimeout.

Comment: @DJYadav Ok, I get it now. Thank you.